# How can i add this label for wheels?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-widget

How can i add this label for wheels?

[image: http://s1.directupload.net/images/130711/wwt58tbv.png]

Comment: That is not a standard Android widget. I guess you are using this: http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/ ?

Comment: +1 because a picture is worth a thousand words

Comment: Yes he is using this widget. Which version are you using?

Comment: i use the latest version where these labels disappeared

Answer (score 0):

There may be a direct xml option. Try android:text="(the name)"

Comment: there is no android:text option

Comment: I guess you should check the documentation for the wheel.